# alexa skill local could not write to dynamodb

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, alexa-skills-kit

I am writing a node.js skill using ask-sdk and using alexa-skill-local to test the endpoint. I need to persist data to DynamoDb in one of the handler. But I keep getting "missing region error". Please find my code below:

```
'use strict';

// use 'ask-sdk' if standard SDK module is installed
const Alexa = require('ask-sdk');

const { launchRequestHandler, HelpIntentHandler, CancelAndStopIntentHandler, SessionEndedRequestHandler } = require('./commonHandlers');

const ErrorHandler = {
    canHandle() {
        return true;
    },
    handle(handlerInput, error) {
        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak('Sorry, I can\'t understand the command. Please say again.')
            .reprompt('Sorry, I can\'t understand the command. Please say again.')
            .getResponse();
    },
};

////////////////////////////////
// Code for the handlers here //
////////////////////////////////
exports.handler = Alexa.SkillBuilders
    .standard()
    .addRequestHandlers(
        launchRequestHandler,
        HelpIntentHandler,
        CancelAndStopIntentHandler,
        SessionEndedRequestHandler,
        ErrorHandler
    )
    .withTableName('devtable')
    .withDynamoDbClient()
    .lambda();
```

And in one of the handler I am trying to get persisted attributes like below:

```
handlerInput.attributesManager.getPersistentAttributes().then((data) => {
    console.log('--- the attributes are ----', data)
})
```

But I keep getting the following error:

```
(node:12528) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: AskSdk.DynamoDbPersistenceAdapter Error: Could not read item (amzn1.ask.account.AHJECJ7DTOPSTT25R36BZKKET4TKTCGZ7HJWEJEBWTX6YYTLG5SJVLZH5QH257NFKHXLIG7KREDKWO4D4N36IT6GUHT3PNJ4QPOUE4FHT2OYNXHO6Z77FUGHH3EVAH3I2KG6OAFLV2HSO3VMDQTKNX4OVWBWUGJ7NP3F6JHRLWKF2F6BTWND7GSF7OVQM25YBH5H723VO123ABC) from table (EucerinSkinCareDev): Missing region in config
    at Object.createAskSdkError (E:\projects\nodejs-alexa-sdk-v2-eucerin-skincare-dev\node_modules\ask-sdk-dynamodb-persistence-adapter\dist\utils\AskSdkUtils.js:22:17)
    at DynamoDbPersistenceAdapter.<anonymous> (E:\projects\nodejs-alexa-sdk-v2-eucerin-skincare-dev\node_modules\ask-sdk-dynamodb-persistence-adapter\dist\attributes\persistence\DynamoDbPersistenceAdapter.js:121:45)
```

Can we read and write attributes from DynamoDb using alexa-skill-local ? Do we need some different setup to achieve this ?

Thanks

Comment: `alexa-skill-local`'s purpose is to create a local development server and update the endpoint in alexa development console. Problem you have mentioned here is related to not providing AWS config profile as mentioned by @Mike in his answer below and not with `alexa-skill-local`. Disclaimer: I am a creator of `alexa-skill-local`.

Answer (score 1):

I know that this is a really old topic, but I had the same problem few days ago, and I'm gonna explain how I did it work.
You have to download DynamoDB Locally and follow the instructions from [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBLocal.DownloadingAndRunning.html)

Once that you have configure your local DynamoDB and check that it is working. You have to pass it through your code, to DynamoDbPersistenceAdapter constructor.
Your code should look similar to:

```
var awsSdk = require('aws-sdk');
var myDynamoDB = new awsSdk.DynamoDB({
    endpoint: 'http://localhost:8000', // If you change the default url, change it here
    accessKeyId: <your-access-key-id>,
    secretAccessKey: <your-secret-access-key>,
    region: <your-region>,
    apiVersion: 'latest'
});

const {DynamoDbPersistenceAdapter} = require('ask-sdk-dynamodb-persistence-adapter');
return new DynamoDbPersistenceAdapter({
    tableName: tableName || 'my-table-name',
    createTable: true,
    dynamoDBClient: myDynamoDB
});
```

Where `<your-acces-key-id>`, `<your-secrete-access-key>` and `<your-region>` are defined at aws config and credentials files.

The next step is launch your server with `alexa-skill-local` command as always.

Hope this will be helpfull! =)

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you have an AWS config profile that your skill is using when running locally.

You need to edit the .config file and set the default region (ie us-east-1) there. The region should match the region where your table exists.

Alternatively, if you want to be able to run completely isolated, you may need to write come conditional logic and swap the dynamo client with one targeting an instance of DynamoDB Local running on your machine.